# Angular 4 showing json in a table

Tags: json, angular, service, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"0": {
"open": 93.3,
"high": 96,
"low": 93.3,
"close": 95.04,
"volume": 358172,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZBRA",
"company_name": "Zebra Technologies Corp.",
"company_sector": "Industrial Goods"
},
"1": {
"open": 19.1396,
"high": 19.5578,
"low": 18.7612,
"close": 19.3587,
"volume": 185112,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZEUS",
"company_name": "Olympic Steel Inc.",
"company_sector": "Industrial Goods"
},
"2": {
"open": 40.4208,
"high": 41.1223,
"low": 39.9614,
"close": 40.0058,
"volume": 6950648,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZION",
"company_name": "Zions Bancorporation",
"company_sector": "Financial"
},
"3": {
"open": 6.86,
"high": 7.27,
"low": 6.86,
"close": 7.09,
"volume": 1391657,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZIOP",
"company_name": "ZIOPHARM Oncology, Inc.",
"company_sector": "Healthcare"
},
"4": {
"open": 5.38,
"high": 5.41,
"low": 5.19,
"close": 5.21,
"volume": 345071,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZIXI",
"company_name": "Zix Corporation",
"company_sector": "Technology"
},
"5": {
"open": 1.2,
"high": 1.2,
"low": 1.15,
"close": 1.15,
"volume": 136149,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZN",
"company_name": "Zion Oil & Gas, Inc.",
"company_sector": "Basic Materials"
},
"6": {
"open": 2.85,
"high": 2.9,
"low": 2.82,
"close": 2.86,
"volume": 6989286,
"score": "100",
"symbol": "ZNGA",
"company_name": "Zynga, Inc.",
"company_sector": "Technology"
}
}
```

I have verified that it is in a json format, and i have the following model to represent it:

```
export interface User {
  open: number;
  high: number;
  low: number;
  close:number;
  volume: number;
  score: string;
  symbol:string;
  company_name:string;
  company_sector:string;
```

}

the service for the json works as intended, but when I try to show the json in a table like that:

```
<font color="white">
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> 
Symbol </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.symbol}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="score">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> Score </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.score}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="open">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> Open </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.open}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="high">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> High </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.high}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="low">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> Low </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.low}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="close">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 25.5%"> Close </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.close}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="company_name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> Company Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company_name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="company_sector">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> Company Sector </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company_sector}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="volume">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width = 12.5%"> Volume </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.volume}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table> 
</div>
</font>
```

I've tried to display it as a table with some guides on the internet but couldn't succeed it always shows an empty table, do you know what can be the problem?

edit:
here is the ts file of the component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/userservice/user.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { EasyService } from '../../services/easysearch/easysearch.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'usertable',
  templateUrl: './usertable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usertable.component.css']
})
export class UsertableComponent   {
  userData = null;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.userData);
  displayedColumns = ['open','high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'score', 
'symbol','company_name', 'company_sector'];



  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
userService.getUser().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.userData = data;
    this.dataSource.data = this.userData;
  });
   }



  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }



}

/*export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.userService.getUser();
      }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;




  disconnect() {}
}*/
```

Here is the service:

```
 import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient }   from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable }   from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
 @Injectable()
 export class EasyService {
  private serviceUrl = 'http://193.106.55.148:8080/easysearch?budget=1';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
   return this.http.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }


}
```

Comment: can you share your component ? would like to see your current approach?

Comment: added it in now :)

Comment: try  `this.dataSource.data = data.body;`

Comment: same result, i get an empty table.

Comment: could you share your service too

Comment: yep,added it in too

Comment: man, I am not able to reproduce your issue it's working as desired  I just tweaked your json a bit to simulate the same response :(

Comment: thank you for sticking with me! can you send me the json you worked with/ stackblitz link if you worked with that site?

Comment: https://angular-j93xbm.stackblitz.io I am making `get` request to assets folder and on local it works fine.

Comment: the table in the link is empty, as it is for me in my angular, unless it shows me something else than for you.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention, on stackblitz its empty I guess stackblitz does not support such feature yet but it's working fine in local. You can see the tweaked json in the assets folder

Comment: oh i see, thank you so much! edit: even in here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j93xbm?embed=1&file=assets/response.json  the table is empty, isnt that the local version?

Comment: see my answer hope it works for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 4 json to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544291/angular-4-json-to-table)

Comment: @feelingunwelcome no it's not dup of that OP is using angular material table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The response you get from `http` is not a JSON array but a JSON object. use **[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** to convert the response into array.

```
userService.getUser().subscribe(
      data => {

        this.dataSource.data = Object.values(data);
      });
```